# Model Relationship Diagram / Database Relationship Diagram

Tags: yii

I need to generate a diagram (UML?!) to show the relationship between my models (either that or generate a diagram to show relationships between tables from the Database).

Is there a library/plugin in Yii to do that?

For extracting the diagram of relationships between tables - I tried using MySQL Workbench, however soon realized that foreign keys are not defined/created on a database level.

What are my options and possible solutions?

Comment: You really should set those FKs. They're super duper important.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @waterloomatt.

I'm currently using LimeSurvey - https://www.limesurvey.org/https://www.limesurvey.org.
The project uses Yii (not yii2 - apologies for that).

I've used phpmyadmin and mysql bench to find the relationship between tables( and determine the relationship between models), however - nothing comes up.

The help boards (limesurveys forum) mentioned they do not use FK's (which sounds strange) - hence trying me luck with how can Yii help

Comment: https://forums.limesurvey.org/forum/can-i-do-this-with-limesurvey/107182-subforms-or-related-forms-or-forms-connected-through-a-foreign-key - which storage engine did you import the database with? You should not use MyISAM because it does not support FKs so won't import them. Try using InnoDB.